# System.IO.FileInfo.Equals() is not returning expected result in Where LINQ extension method

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.fileinfo

When attempting to return all other files from the same directory that a specified file resides in, the files being returned are including the specified file. Lets assume I have three files out in a server share on my network:

- `\\Server\Share\Path\To\file1.ext`
- `\\Server\Share\Path\To\file2.ext`
- `\\Server\Share\Path\To\file3.ext`

When I attempt to filter out file2 using the `.Equals()` method on the `FileInfo` object, the file is still being included.

```
FileInfo theFile = new FileInfo(@"\\Server\Share\Path\To\file2.ext");
List<FileInfo> allOtherFilesList = theFile.Directory.EnumerateFiles("*").Where(f => !f.Equals(vidFile)).ToList();

//Returned files:
\\Server\Share\Path\To\file1.ext
\\Server\Share\Path\To\file2.ext
\\Server\Share\Path\To\file3.ext
```

If I use the `.Equals()` method on the `FileInfo.FullName` property, I am returned a list of files as I would expect

```
FileInfo theFile = new FileInfo(@"\\Server\Share\Path\To\file2.ext");
List<FileInfo> allOtherFilesList = theFile.Directory.EnumerateFiles("*").Where(f => !f.FullName.Equals(vidFile.FullName)).ToList();

//Returned files:
\\Server\Share\Path\To\file1.ext
\\Server\Share\Path\To\file3.ext
```

Surely, there is some aspect of the `.Equals()` method that I'm not understanding? I would have thought that two `FileInfo` objects representing the same file would be the same.

Comment: Did you have time to check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8 to see if `FileInfo` has `Equals` method?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - The `.Equals()` method is a base method for the `object` type of which all .NET objects inherit from.

Comment: @вʀaᴎᴅᴏƞвєнᴎєƞ That doesn't mean that classes override `Equals`.  I think the base version just does a reference equals.

Comment: As @Zer0 mentioned, FileInfo does not override `Equals`. So the result is correct, these are two different objects, just pointing to the same file.